# Android Geofence example as aService

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am trying to implement the android developers Geofence sample as a background service in my application. I want to convert the GeoActivity to a service. How can I do that...Or is there any way to run this activity in background and having another activity running in the foreground??

the code is in:
 http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: No, you have to turn it into an actual Service. Which shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate class which extends Service and implement geofence insertion there.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service{
 your geofence insertion logic here....
}
```

Now from any other Activity call `startService` method which takes an intent as argument.

It could be as :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
Intent backgroundService;
backgroundService = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
startService(backgroundService);
```

}

Dont forget to declare the service as child of your application in your manifest.